# probability of drawing two card simultaneously

Tags: probability

For e.g what is the probability that both card drawn from a deck of card will be king.

Is drawing two card simultaneously and drawing one after the other(not replaced back), the same thing.

Because when we draw two card simultaneously, isn't their probability that they will be king should be same i.e 4/52 * 4/52.

I know the probability when two card are drawn one after the other is 4/52 * 3/51.

Thanks.

Comment: If in real world you pick two cards "simultaneously" then I bet that one of the cards can be labeled as the one that was touched by your fingers as first. So there is always an order. Even if this order seems to be absent in the abstract setting then you can build in some order yourself. That can be fruitful in many situations.

Answer (score 1):

Two cards drawn simultaneously is the same as drawing one card after the other without replacement. Specifically, if you draw two cards simultaneously, the two cannot be the same card.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is the same thing.

In both situations, picking a certain card will prevent you from picking that same card as your "second" card. And here "second" doesn't necessarily mean you pick it afterwards. The point is that, even if you pick it at the same time as the first, it still can't be the same as the first. And that restriction is what makes the probability be $\frac{4}{52}\times\frac{3}{51}$ in either case